# Is it possible to set drawableLeft programmatically?

Tags: android

In XML we can set drawableLeft using this way:

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/previewBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/white_btn"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/green_circle"
    android:drawablePadding="16dp"
    android:text="Button" />
```

How to do same thing programmatically?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, use [setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

and define the drawable for the first parameter, then 0 for all the others.

The code should look something like this:

```
Button b = findViewById(R.id.myButton);

b.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.myDrawable, 0, 0, 0);
```

If your drawable was created in code as well then you need to use the other [setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) method which takes 4 drawables, and pass null for all but the left.

Answer (score 2):

The method to use is [setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29). This method takes all four drawable options (left, top, right, bottom), so if you want only left, pass in `null` for the others.

Comment: what if i want to put in center